# How can I namespace some js jquery within rails 4?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, namespaces, asset-pipeline

I'm including

```
$ cat app/assets/javascripts/linker_namespace.js
Linker = {}
```

in my asset pipeline

I try to use it with an asset, e.g. for

```
$(function(){
  var updateUi = function (event) {
      event.defaultPrevented;
      $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
      $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
      toggle_server_details_flag_silently();
  };  

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    updateUi(event);
  }); 

});
```

I add Linker as in

```
$(function(){
  var Linker.updateUi = function (event) {
      event.defaultPrevented;
      $("span.show_hide").toggleClass("shown hidden");
      $("table").toggleClass("wide narrow");
      toggle_server_details_flag_silently();
  };  

  $("a[data-toggle-description-length]='toggle'").click(function(event){
    Linker.updateUi(event);
  }); 

});
```

but in the browser I get

```
SyntaxError: missing ; before statement for line 2
```

Comment: Isn't it a jQuery event object? In that case use event.preventDefault(); instead event.defaultPrevented;

Comment: true but doesn't seem to be the issue here.  I changed it and didn't fix this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the var from inside the function, i.e. change

```
 var Linker.updateUi = function (event) {
```

to

```
 Linker.updateUi = function (event) {
```